# How to intentionally move to second jhana

Tags: jhana

I have mastered the 1st and wish to move now to the second. But all the books and sources online confuse me. Some say it happen naturally other say it's something you can focus on to bring about the second jhana like thoughts on how unpleasant the 1st is. So how can i summon the second at will?

Answer (score 3):

Ajahn Brahm gives a very nice explanation about how to get into higher Jhnanas. Imagine that you are in a long corridor with soap water on the floor and you play the game where you come running and slide on the slope water in order to get to another side of the corridor. In this case, the more energy you will slide within the beginning the farther you will get, and in all process, you have to **Let-go**. So as per my information, you have to further Let-go, to get there. You cannot summon it with the will, the will has to be dropped.

I will recommend you to read *Mindfulness, Bliss and Beyond* by Ajahn Brahm -- that will answer the question in great detail.

And maybe this will help: [The Basic Method of Meditation](https://bswa.org/bswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ajahn-brahm_the-basic-method-of-meditation.pdf) (by Ajahn Brahm)

Comment: Thank you for the source. So to reach the second jhana abandoned applied and sustained thought this happen when you end attachment to 1st by seeing the flaws and annoyance of it after emerging from it. Then moving your attention away from the object to a the pleasant sensation. That will lead you to the 2nd. Allow rapture and pleasure to fill the whole body

Comment: Take me with a pinch of salt but I think you will enter the second directly from the first not by emerging out of it. But idk. I think you emerge out, you mark it as experience and second time go back with more energy in first, let go, and it should take you in second. But idk.

Comment: BTW congrats bro...you acheived great feet...just 3 more and you are done....best wishes!

Comment: So maybe i already have lol. And thanks bud it took a while. This site truly helped me